# Profile <activation> by substring of a property?

Tags: maven

I discovered profiles today, and changed my `pom.xml` to use them -- to produce two different "flavors" ("ONE" and "TWO") of the resulting artifacts from the same the code.

Though the code is the same, the dependencies are (slightly) different between the flavors.

Because the dependencies are local (accessed via `<systemPath>`), I specify the actual location on command-line: `-Dfoo.jars=/path/to/the/jars`. I also specify desired profile: `-PONE` or `-PTWO`.

This works nicely, but I'd like to shorted the command line by having the right profile activated *automatically* depending on the value of the `foo.jars` property: if the path contains substring "one", it shall pick profile "ONE", otherwise -- "TWO".

An answer to a similar question asked earlier suggested the use of `build-helper-maven-plugin` (from org.codehaus.mojo) and so I tried:

```xml
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ONE</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>foo.target</name>
                    <value>ONE</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            ...
            </properties>
        </profile>
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <name>foo.target</name>
                    <value>${foo.jars}</value>
                    <regex>.*(ONE|TWO).*</regex>
                    <replacement>\1</replacement>
                    <toUpperCase>true</toUpperCase>
                    <fileSet/>
                    <source/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Although there are no obvious errors parsing the regex, *neither* profile is picked and properties I need defined depending on the chosen profile, remain undefined...

Could someone share a working example?